# File is not being copied to a valid directory

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate, copy

Ubuntu_Documents.zip is not being copied to Local_Backup_Dir?

/home/andy/Backup/Ubuntu_Mate_20.04/ does exist.

Other files are being copied to that directory.

Can someone offer some things I can check?

Thanks.

```
Backup_Directory="/media/andy/Maxtor/Backup/"
Local_Backup_Dir="/home/andy/Backup/Ubuntu_Mate_20.04/"

cd $DOCS
touch Blank.odt
zip -u Ubuntu_Documents.zip *.txt *.doc *.rtf *.html *.png *.pdf *.odt *.ods *.odg *.csv *.xls *.jpg 
## ONLY copy file if it's newer than destination file
##
rsync --progress -r -u Ubuntu_Documents.zip $Backup_Directory
rsync --progress -r -u Ubuntu_Documents.zip $Local_Backup_Dir
```

Using the pathlld.sh script, I got this.

```
andy@7 ~/bin> pathlld.sh /home/andy/Backup/Ubuntu_Mate_20.04/Ubuntu_Documents.zip
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Nov 12 22:46 /
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 12 21:08 /home
drwxr-x--- 31 andy andy 4096 Nov 28 18:38 /home/andy
drwxrwxr-x 7 andy andy 4096 Nov 18 06:59 /home/andy/Backup
drwxrwxr-x 4 andy andy 4096 Nov 28 22:20 /home/andy/Backup/Ubuntu_Mate_20.04
-rw-rw-r-- 1 andy andy 35287502 Nov 28 20:52 /home/andy/Backup/Ubuntu_Mate_20.04/Ubuntu_Documents.zip
```

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: I do not understand "<file> ...". of pathlld.sh. @waltinator

Comment: That's computet-soeak for "a file, or a bunch of filrs". Each of the objects you're curious about.